# Can unnamed structures inherit?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, unnamed-class

The following looks like a compilation error :

```
struct : Base { };
```

Yet when [used](http://ideone.com/u4LqG6) <sup>[1]</sup> it seems to work :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<bool B>
struct A 
{
    struct : std::integral_constant<bool, B> {
    } members;
};

int main()
{
    A<true> a;    
    cout << a.members.value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In c++ is it valid for unnamed structures to inherit? Are there any examples where this is userful?

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> Disclaimer: I'm not pretending the provided example is useful. I rarely use unnamed structs, and when I do they're usually bundling together some built-in member variables, in order to provide a cleaner interface for a class. The question came up from the observation that [memberspaces](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3016/An-STL-like-bidirectional-map#from_and_to) need not be nammed structures</sup>

Comment: the second example is valid. The use for it? Yet to be determined.

Comment: @StoryTeller: https://ideone.com/CWXUkv

Comment: @lorro Wow, quite a throwback. Neat trick, but `std::tie` is the better approach IMO.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I don't really like std::tie as it requires you to first construct a possibly invalid object. What if it's a resource, what if we have no default constructor, what if it takes time / allocation to construct? To put it the other way, I hope some day we'll be allowed to declare variables anywhere, including inside std::tie (or make tie). It wouldn't be worse than inside for / if / while...

Comment: @lorro, Rejoice, this seems to have made it into C++17 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf

Comment: Yippie :) - albeit I don't like the syntax, it's a quantum leap forward.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unnamed classes can inherit. This is useful, for example, in situations when you *must* inherit in order to override a virtual function, but you never need more than one instance of the class, and you do not need to reference the derived type, because a reference to the base type is sufficient.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {virtual int process(int a, int b) = 0;};
static struct : Base {
    int process(int a, int b) { return a+b;}    
} add;
static struct : Base {
    int process(int a, int b) { return a-b;}    
} subtract;
static struct : Base {
    int process(int a, int b) { return a*b;}    
} multiply;
static struct : Base {
    int process(int a, int b) { return a/b;}    
} divide;

void perform(Base& op, int a, int b) {
    cout << "input: " << a << ", " << b << "; output: " << op.process(a, b) << endl;
}

int main() {
    perform(add, 2, 3);
    perform(subtract, 6, 1);
    perform(multiply, 6, 7);
    perform(divide, 72, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

This code creates four anonymous derivations of `Base` - one for each operation. When the instances of these derivations are passed to the `perform` function, the proper override is called. Note that `perform` does not need to know about any of the specific types - the base type with its virtual function is enough to complete the process.

Here is the output of running the above code:

```
input: 2, 3; output: 5
input: 6, 1; output: 5
input: 6, 7; output: 42
input: 72, 8; output: 9
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/b7XDaY)

Answer (score 9):

Your first example, because it doesn't declare anything, shows an attempt at an anonymous struct (which is not allowed - 7/3) rather than an unnamed one (which is).

The grammar in 9/1 of the C++11 standard seems to allow an unnamed class to have a base, so I think your second example is fine.