# Why is operator= from a base class not a candidate when assigning to a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

While trying to answer [C++ bare getter setter with dispatch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226262/), I thought of the following solution to create a class that implements getter/setter like behavior, while avoiding any macros:

```
template<typename T>
class property
{
protected:
    T v;

    virtual const T &get(void) const {
        return v;
    }

    virtual void set(const T &o) {
        v = o;
    }

public:
    property() {}
    property(T v_): v(v_) {}
    property &operator=(const T &o) {set(o); return *this;}
    operator T() const {return get();}
};
```

Which could then be used to create member variables that can have custom getter and/or setter functions, like so:

```
struct example {
    // Variable with default getter/setter
    struct: property<int> {} foo;

    // Variable with custom setter
    struct: property<int> {
        void set(const int &o) { v = o * o; }
    } bar;
};
```

The above code compiles without any problem, but as soon as I try to use it I get an error that there is no viable candidate function when trying to assign to such a property variable:

```
int main() {
    example e;
    e.foo = 42;
}
```

The output from clang++ is:

```
getset.cpp:40:8: error: no viable overloaded '='
        e.foo = 42;
        ~~~~~ ^ ~
getset.cpp:31:2: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const example::(anonymous class at getset.cpp:31:2)' for 1st argument
        class: encapsulate<int> {
        ^
getset.cpp:31:2: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'example::(anonymous class at getset.cpp:31:2)' for 1st argument
        class: encapsulate<int> {
        ^
```

The error message suggests that `property::operator=()` is never considered. Making `property::set()` public and calling `e.foo.set(42)` works fine. Making a public, non-virtual member function in `class property` that calls `set()` also works fine. Creating a bare property variable and setting it works fine:

```
property<int> i;
i = 42; // works fine
```

Why is `property::operator=()` not a candidate when assigning to a derived class?

Comment: What are the `struct:` labels supposed to do?

Comment: Google for "C++ hiding rule".  It's a specific rule in the standard which says that a member of a base class will be hidden by a member of the same name in the derived class.   Hiding means that the derived class version is preferred as a match when the compiler would otherwise consider both versions as candidates.   `operator=()` is implicitly defined by the compiler (assuming appropriate conditions are met) and the derived class versions therefore hides the base class versions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - the `struct:` isn't a label.   It's just defining an anonymous `struct` type (one with no name) that is derived (in this case) from `property<int>`.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! I see how that works now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo see [Can unnamed structures inherit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979785/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Got it! I did get tricked by the inheritance.

Comment: Then, wouldn't `using property<int>::operator=;` fix it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: indeed, that fixes it, although now you have to explicitly write that out everytime you declare a derived `property<>` variable. I was hoping to keep the notation as terse as possible.

Comment: Stink it, was about to answer... oh well.